# App Inventor: problem retrieving data from firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, app-inventor

I store some location data in firebase:

[image: firebase data structure]
When I try to retrieve the location data in App Inventor, I found that the data I get is not a list:

[image: App Inventor error]

Does anyone know how I can do with the data I get from the firebase database? (the data I got is "{Nick_Name="Ken", Address="60 Old Mill Rd, Oakville, ON L6J 7V9, Canada\n", Latitude=43.452752, Longitude=-79.68407404}")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to use the **JsonTextDecode** method from the Web component to get a list of lists

[image]